# JSpinner returning wrong type

Tags: java, swing, classcastexception, jspinner

This is really confusing. I have a bunch of `JSpinner` components in my application, and they all work fine. I have their models set to be a range of integer values. They are declared like so:

```
spinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
spinner1.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(10, 0, 10, 1));
```

When I need their values in the code, I'll call `getValue()` which returns an object and I cast it as an integer like so:

```
int importantVal = (Integer)spinner1.getValue();
```

And this has been working fine. For some reason I've made a new JSpinner, with the exact same SpinnerNumberModel, but I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
   java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

It's giving me back a float for some reason. I verified the Model is the same, I tried copying and pasting a working JSpinner into this new one's role and matched the name but I still have the same problem. Out of curiosity I tried changing the line where I have this error to cast it as a Float instead, and then I get the reverse of the error: it returns an Integer and now i'm trying to cast it as a float.

Why would it flip flop like that, and how could it return a float? I even tried setting the model using `new SpinnerNumberModel(new Integer(10), new Integer(0), new Integer(10), new Integer(1))` but naturally that doesn't change anything...

Comment: This might be a stretch, but consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, if possible showing both a working spinner and your naughty spinner. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I like to side step the casts by directly using the model to both create the spinner and query the value.  That might work better here.  If not, post a [mcve] as advised by @MadProgrammer - as there is not enough code to determine the immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

As people pointed out, I didn't post enough to determine the problem. There was nothing wrong with how I was declaring my JSpinner, which is why they normally worked. It was a mistake elsewhere in this unruly application that caused the problem:

I had a function which was accidentally setting the value of the JSpinner with a float, and this is why it was returning a float. I didn't realize it but a SpinnerNumberModel with a value/min/max/step size declared as ints, can be given a float value. And it will have the min/max/step size stay as ints but the value be a float.

Whoops

Comment: Good catch. This is useful to know, and entirely understandable how you fell into this trap. In hindsight it's clear that the model uses Number as its value type and thus is entirely ambiguous about the concrete type of number at runtime, but it's really not very intuitive.